# Error getting image path selected by Gallery Intent (Android 6 - Some devices)

Tags: android

I am trying to get the path of an image when the user pick from the gallery (with intent)

It's been working ok, since some users noticed that could not do it witn Android 6.0.

I have tried different things, and some solutions works in the emulator with Android 6.0 but not in my Xiamoi with Android 6.1.

This both solutions works in the emulator (6.0) and Android 4.4 physycal device.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Activity context, Uri contentURI) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = context.managedQuery(contentURI, projection, null,
            null, null);
    if (cursor == null)
        return null;
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String s = cursor.getString(column_index);
        // cursor.close();
        return s;
    }
    // cursor.close();
    return null;
}
```

and the other similar:

```
private static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But in my Xiaomi 6.1 the cursor is null. But I can get the real path from:

```
private static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    return contentUri.getEncodedPath();
}
```

Any help?
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I'm asking for choose an image in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK); //ACTION_GET_CONTENT
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
launchForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
```

Comment: At best, your code will work if you are *specifically* requesting from the `MediaStore`. Even then, the resulting path may be useless to you, as the content may be located on removable storage. I suggest that you get rid of all of this, and simply [use the `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

Comment: I edit my question to show how I'm requesting. Isn't it the correct way to request? How can I do it from MediaStore?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm asking for choose an image in this way:

First, use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to pick by MIME type.

Second, whatever activity that responds to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (or `ACTION_PICK`) does not need to return a `Uri` that the `MediaStore` knows about. In fact, most will not. They can return a `Uri` that points to *anything*, including things that are not files.

So, get rid of all of your broken `getRealPathFromURI()` code. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, and use that stream.